# Upsert into a table and deleting a row from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am doing an upsert into say `table1` with a composite primary key on `col1, col3`. I understand I can do it as

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4) 
values (val1, val2, val3, val4) 
    on conflict(col1, col3) do update set ......
```

I am aware of the notion of `Excluded` and all.

My dilemma is that when this conflict happens, I want to delete a row from `table2` that has specific values in corresponding columns in `table1`. How do I do this in a single upsert query?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why not use 2 separate queries: One with DELETE and the other with INSERT, but
I think using CTE is good option:

```
WITH inserting(col1, col2, col3, col4) AS (
    VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4) 
),
deleting AS (
    DELETE FROM table1 AS t USING inserting i
    WHERE t.col1 = i.col1 AND t.col3 = i.col3
)
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4) TABLE inserting;
```

Here is fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2kibo6nMux3BBbuSRAhDgj/0

Answer (score 0):

See example.

Test data

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (col1 int4, col2 int4, col3 int4, col4 int4
  ,constraint uix_col1_col2 unique(col1,col2));
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES 
  (1,1,3,3)
,(5,5,5,3)
,(1,2,3,4)
;
create table table2(val1 int,val2 int);
insert into table2 values
 (1,10)
,(5,5)
;
```

Check constraint. Ok.

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES 
  (1,2,6,7)
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uix_col1_col2"
DETAIL:  Key (col1, col2)=(1, 2) already exists.
```

Test data before request.
Table1

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

table2

| val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 5 | 5 |

Upsert

```
with data(col1,col2,col3,col4) as (
   values(5,5,50,30),(6,6,60,90)
)
,ins as(
  insert into table1 
  select * from data
  on conflict (col1,col2) do nothing
  returning *
)
delete from table2 t2
  using(
   select d.col1,d.col2,i.col1 col1x,i.col2 col2x
   from data d
   left join ins i on i.col1=d.col1 and i.col2=d.col2 
  )x
where x.col1=t2.val1 and x.col2=t2.val2 and col1x is null
  ;
```

Result
Table1

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 6 | 6 | 60 | 90 |

Table2

| val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |